# How can I add a variable in to a character string in R? I'm basically trying to parameterize a character string, as I would in SQL

Tags: r, sqldf

My R code below.  Note below are two character strings; I am trying to parameterize the "query" string #by adding in the perspective variable so that if I want to change the query string perspective, I only #need to update the perspective variable.

```
perspective <- 'GR'

query <- "select portname, description, sum(loss) as 'perspective'_loss
          from table1
          where perspcode = 'perspective'"
```

Comment: `paste0("select portname, description, sum(loss) as", perspective, "_loss from table1 where perspcode = 'perspective'")`?

Answer (score 1):

**1) fn$** Preface the command which has the SQL statement with fn$ and then you can do it as shown. Note that the variable interpolated into the string should only have letters and numbers in its name since it assumes the first character which is not one of those ends the name. fn$ comes from gsubfn.  Actually sqldf already loads gsubfn but if you are not using sqldf, e.g. maybe you are using RSQLite, then you will need that library call.

```
library(sqldf)
library(gsubfn) 

Species <- "setosa"
fn$sqldf("select count(*) as count from iris where Species = '$Species'")
##   count
## 1    50
```

For more info see ?fn and also see the examples on the sqldf github home page. https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf

**2) sprintf** We can alternately use `sprintf`:

```
sql <- sprintf("select count(*) as count from iris where Species = '%s'", Species)
sqldf(sql)
```

**3) paste** Using paste or paste0 is another alternative but the above seem easier.